# INSERT INTO statement for Access in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I am developing a website.

My connection string in web.config is as below:

```
"add name="MyDbConn1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Program Files\QWIN 2000Q\Database\qwin_5501q.mdb;""
```

I already retrieve several times from that database using that connection string. They are working.

But When I insert into a table, error pop ups that "syntax error in INSERT INTO statement".

The below is my codes for insert into statement.

```
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtUser.Text);
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPwd.Text);
command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", ddlAccess.SelectedItem.ToString());
string abc = "Insert into Report_User (Name, Password, Role) VALUES (@Name,@Password,@Role);";
```

When I run that statement in the Microsoft Access, there is no error.

Anyone?

Is there any folder sharing permission or some sort??

Comment: Try doing an insert without parameters first. One of your parameters is probably invalid. so try string abc = "Insert into Report_User (Name, Password, Role) VALUES ('testName','testPassword,'testRole');";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace SQL paramter names a la `@Name` with OleDB-specific parameter placeholder `?`

```
Insert into Report_User (Name, Password, Role) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

change `command2.Parameters.Add(..)` accordingly.

Comment: Actually it is the "Password". I change to "Pwd" then it is OK.